# remove portion of a column in a .tab in unix

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

Can someone please help!  I'm trying to delete the last portion (following "_cO") in the second column of the following list in the bash shell. E.G where it says "_seq1" in this particular list.  I do not want to change any other info in the remaining columns.
Thanks!

```
XP_003962102    comp1000054_c0_seq1 24.07   54  41  0   164 3   
XP_003962102    comp1000054_c0_seq1 24.07   54  41  0   164 3   
XP_003962102    comp1000054_c0_seq1 24.07   54  41  0   164 3   
XP_003962102    comp1000054_c0_seq1 24.07   54  41  0   164 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, a simple substitution using `sed`:

```
sed -e s/_seq1//
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
sed -i.bak 's/^\(.*_c0\)[^ ]*\( .*\)$/\1\2/' file
```

OR using awk:

```
awk '{sub(/_c0[^ ]*/, "_c0", $2)} 1' file
```